# How can we update pivot table range in apache-poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi, pivot-table

I have created a pivot table in the sheet with the data present in the sheet. Now I want to update the range of the pivot table in code. How can I get the name of the pivot table and update the range of the table in apache poi. Please help me with the code part!

Comment: I am not asking about the creation of pivot table, I am asking regarding updating the range of pivot table. I couldn't find this in google So I have asked here. I would be happy if someone could help me.